# Monad Transformer missing parameter (?)

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I've got this type alias:

```
type Board a = ReaderT String (StateT String IO) a
```

I know that `StateT` has the kind `* -> (* -> *) -> * -> *` so it should get three parameters. But in the above example, `StateT` only receives `String` and the `IO`-Monad.
Now I'm wondering where the missing parameter is passed to `StateT`.

Same goes for `IO` which should get one parameter but doesn't get any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [the definition of `ReaderT`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.9/transformers-0.5.6.2/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#t:ReaderT), you will see that its second parameter is itself applied to its last parameter:

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
                                                     ^^^
                                                  right here
```

Which means that its second parameter `m` must have kind `m :: * -> *`. And this is exactly what you get if you apply only two, not three, parameters to `StateT`:

```
StateT :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
StateT x y :: * -> *
(where x :: * and y :: * -> *)
```

When substituting the definition of `ReaderT` in your type `Board`, you'll get:

```
(1) type Board a = ReaderT String (StateT String IO) a

-- Substituting ReaderT definition (pseudocode)
(2) type Board a = { runReaderT :: String -> StateT String IO a }
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                Look, StateT has all its three parameters!
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks a lot! Your example was really helpful. I think I got it now.

Answer (score 3):

You correctly observe that

> `StateT` has the kind `* -> (* -> *) -> * -> *`

and the same is true of `ReaderT`.

So it takes 3 "parameters" as you call them. The first is `String`, of kind `*`, and the third is `a`, again of kind `*`. While the second must be of kind `* -> *`.

And that is given in your example by `StateT String IO`. So although there is in one sense a "missing parameter" of `StateT`, this needs to be "missing" in order to get something of kind `* -> *` - if you tried something like `type Board a = ReaderT String (StateT String IO Int) a`, this would fail with a "kind error", precisely because `ReaderT`'s second type argument needs to be of kind `* -> *`, not of kind `*` which `StateT String IO Int` would have.

The same applies to why `IO` is used on its own rather than something of the form `IO a`. `StateT String (IO Int)` wouldn't work because `StateT` needs to apply to something of kind `* -> *` as its second type argument - `IO` has this kind but `IO Int` (or anything of the form `IO a`) does not.

To take a step back, monad transformers like `ReaderT` and `StateT` transform another monad, and a monad must always be of kind `* -> *`. `IO` is a monad, and so is `StateT String IO`. But `IO Int` and `StateT String IO Int` are not monads - and not for failing the monad laws or anything like that, but for a much more fundamental meaning, they are the wrong kind. (They are "concrete types" - types which have values - rather than "type constructors" that take another type as an argument.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your long explanation! I think I got it now,
> So it takes 3 "parameters" as you call them
How would you call them? I thought "parameters" is the right name

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, I'd probably use "arguments" myself but I'm not sure what the "correct" term if or even if there is one.

Comment: Ah yeah. "Arguments" makes more sense. I thought there might be a Haskell specific term.

Comment: These are literally called "parameters". If you want to be more precise about it - "type parameters".